# Python Logger object is not callable

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a module to use it in different scripts

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler


_logger_name = "Nagios"
_print_format = "%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
_level = logging.DEBUG

class Log():


    def __init__(self,log_file,logger_name=_logger_name,level=_level):
        self.log_file = log_file
        self.logger_name = logger_name
        self.level = level

    def getLog(self):

        """
        Return the logging object

        """
       _logger = logging.getLogger(self.logger_name)
       _logger.setLevel(self.level)
       _logger.addHandler(self._rotateLog())

       return _logger

    def _rotateLog(self):

       """
       Rotating the log files if it exceed the size
       """
       rh = RotatingFileHandler(self.log_file,
                             maxBytes=20*1024*1024, backupCount=2)
       formatter = logging.Formatter(_print_format)
       rh.setFormatter(formatter)
       return rh

log = Log("kdfnknf").getLog()
log("hello")
```

I see the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "nagiosLog.py", line 45, in <module>
  log("hello")
TypeError: 'Logger' object is not callable
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error,

When debugged using pdb I do see it returns the object and printing the dir(log) I don't see the Logger module in it.

Am I missing something here

Answer (score 9):

`log("Hello")`

This is wrong.
Correct is

```
log.info("Hello")
```

log must be printed with logging level i.e. info/error/warning

Answer (score 3):

See the [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) docs:

You have to use a function, you can't just call Logger:

> Logger.**info**(msg, *args, **kwargs)
>
> Logs a message with level INFO on
> this logger. The arguments are interpreted as for debug().

or

> Logger.**warning**(msg, *args, **kwargs)
>
> Logs a message with level WARNING on this logger. The arguments are >interpreted as for debug().

so instead, do:

```
log.info("Test info level logging...")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as OP. Old instructions on implementing custom logging levels will have code that calls the logger constructor, instead of the `log` method. The newer-than-that-but-not-all-that-new functionality is to use `self._log.log(level, et al...`

Edit to add:
so, instead of `log("hello")` you'd need to call `log.log(logging.INFO, "hello")`  or write a wrapper for that function in the Log class that hardcoded the level you want everything logged at and takes only the the message.

Comment: this is the reason he's getting "logger module not callable" he's followed outdated instructions on how to use the logger.  you can't call the constructor anymore to log to a file, you have to call the "log" method of the logger.